# Firefox add-on: trigger content area context menu on a node in page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I trigger the browser's menu popup #contentAreaContextMenu at a specific node in the page document?

In my add-on I have worked out this

```
let windowUtil = require("sdk/window/utils");

let win = windowUtil.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
let popup = win.document.querySelector("#contentAreaContextMenu");
popup.openPopup(null, "", 194, 264, true, false);
```

Which opens the context menu popup I want, but it is unfiltered / has no context
I need to trigger at an image in the page document.

The first argument in the openPopup method is called 'anchor' and sounds like what I am after, but I have no managed it to work.

```
popup.openPopup(imageNodeInPageDocument ..)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The handlers of the popup will look at the [menupopup.triggerNode property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/triggerNode) in order to see what element it was opened for. The way you are currently opening the popup this property will not be set. [Starting with Firefox 4](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383930) you can specify the optional `triggerEvent` parameter when calling `openPopup()`:

```js
var event = new CustomEvent("myCustomEvent");

// Make sure event.target is set correctly
imageNodeInPageDocument.dispatchEvent(event);

popup.openPopup(null, "", 194, 264, true, false, event);
```

This should make sure the context menu knows which element it is being opened for.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir I'll try that later today. I got around it by using document.createEvent and initMouseEvent

Comment: I thought triggerNode is read-only. I might be mistaken, but I gave an alternative answer for people who bump on this question like I did.

Comment: @R-U-Bn: You are right, it is read-only - meaning that setting it is somewhat more complicated. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

What about..

```
    mynode.setAttribute("context", "contentAreaContextMenu");
```

Comment: The question is about opening the context menu programmatically.